# Should I always use the private access modifier for class fields?

Tags: java, checkstyle

Currently we are running [checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) on our code base and it flags up any non-static class fields that don't use the **private** access modifier.

Is this a valid checkstyle rule, or are there situations where having non-private fields is desirable? For example, I thought the reason JUnit test cases are created in the same package was so that they could access fields using the **default** access modifier?

Comment: Not sure I understand what a non-static class field is? Do you mean non-private member variables?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the main features of object orientated programming is information hiding/encapsulation. This means a class allows access to member variables only via an interface: getter and setter methods. So other classes cannot access the member variables and modify them in an unwanted way. So the checkstyle rule is valid

Comment: Should I use an interface for everything? Even beans?

Comment: by _Interface_ I don't mean a Java `Interface` but the methods that a class provides to the outside to access its members.

Answer (score 6):

*Item 13 of Effective Java 2nd: Minimize the accessibility of classes and members.*

Check this out. It gives great ideas.

Comment: Thanks, this is in the post at the moment but it doesn't answer my question immediately.

Answer (score 6):

IMHO Its best to make fields `private` and `final` where ever possible.  For unit tests however, it may be a pragmatic choice to make them package-private or access them via reflection.  (Which amounts to the same thing)

You can also take the approach of black-box testing which means unless you can determine what has happened via a public method, it shouldn't be tested. (Or your tests need to be more contrived)

Answer (score 2):

Private access or finality is not a problem for advanced mocking frameworks  like JMockit. However,  getter/setter may have some performance penatly on onlder versions of android

Comment: Fortunately, I'm not using Android in this case.

Answer (score 1):

In general it makes sense to use private fields but there are exceptions to the rule. One possible exception is where you're dealing with data transfer objects (DTOs) and you want to communicate clearly to the client that setting the value of a property will not produce a change on the backend. Public fields are a nice way of communicating that.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a good valid rule that ensures information hiding is being done correctly - which is an important facet of OOP.

Use Public getter and setter methods instead where the object can control changes to its state.

Comment: +0: Using a public getter may expose the field more broadly than a package-private field. I wouldn't consider this an improvement. ;)